# Dropdown bootstrap isn't display up the scroll bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've the following code using bootstrap:

```
    <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
        <div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;">


            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled">
                    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DwQIi6ipDgN9LIOe5TqR?p=preview

When I click on the dropdown, it displays under the scrollbar, how can I make it to display on top of the scrollbar?

This is screenshot for my problem:
[image]

I want to do the following: (Edit)
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your still looking for an answer to this you can try

```
<div style="width:200px;height:100px;line-height:3em;overflow:auto;padding:5px;">
```

this will move the scroll bar to the side of the dropdown instead of the side of the page

For the issue of the dropdown going under the scrolbar you need to change the direction the box opens from, in bootstrap its position is set to absolute and left:0; you need to change this to right:0;

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;    <--- change this to right:0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean you want the dropdown menu to go up? If so check here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup

Ok still not to sure what you mean but I think maybe try, in your code on line:14

```
<div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;">
```

The 100px height and overflow is causing the scrollbar to appear remove those.

Comment: No, see the screenshot(Edit) what I want to do.

Comment: I want to leave the height of the div!

Answer (score -1):

Line 14 has the following code:

```
<div style="height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;">
```

However, this is limiting your drop down to be only 100px in height. Interestingly, this is right after the second line of text.

To fix, remove the height and overflow-y portions of style. in this case, you can just have a single `<div>`

Comment: I want to leave the height of the div!

Comment: @RamzyAbourafeh ok, then your drop down won't be any larger than 100px :P.

Comment: No man, I added a screenshot from my project, see my problem please

Comment: @RamzyAbourafeh to be fair, your original post was not at all clear about your current problem. I don't think this is something you can fix, I believe it's a browser setting.